# Error MSB6006 "al.exe" exited with code -1073741819 - Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I try to run asp.net core application but visual studio displays error:

```
Error MSB6006 "al.exe" exited with code -1073741819 -  LocalizationApp Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets
```

Guys maybe you know what mean this error?

I have very simple asp.net core app with implementation localizaton.

**startup file**:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");           
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            var supportedCultures = new[]
            {
                new CultureInfo("en"),
                new CultureInfo("ru")
            };

            app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
            {
                DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("ru"),
                SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
                SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
            });

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```